# How to handle subsequest anchor tag click for filtering data with ASP.NET core routes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

I am using.NET 6 MVC Project template. I am getting stucked in to handle subsequest anchor tag click to achieve mutliple paramaters data filter. I achieve the single attribute filtering but i am getting stucked in if user click subsequent attribute after filtering with attribute. I successfully map the routes but i have no idea how to handle it with anchor tags.

What i achieved in building anchor tags link:
https://localhost:7026/home/index/category/gen/

What i want to achieve if category already clicked and then user click topic:
https://localhost:7026/home/index/category/gen/topic/bs

Controller Code:

```
 public IActionResult Index(string? topicId, string? categoryId)
 {
     List<FAQ> faqList = new List<FAQ>();
     faqList = _dbContext.FAQs.Include(t => t.Topic).Include(c => c.Category).ToList();

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(topicId))
     {
         faqList = faqList.Where(x => x.TopicId == topicId.ToUpper()).ToList();

     }
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryId))
     {
         faqList = faqList.Where(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId.ToUpper()).ToList();
     }

     var categories = _dbContext.Categories.ToList();
     ViewBag.Categories = categories;

     return View(faqList);
 }
```

**Here is my code of Routes:**

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "category_topic",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/Category/{categoryId?}/Topic/{topicId?}");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "topic_category",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/Topic/{topicId?}/Category/{categoryId?}");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "category",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/Category/{categoryId?}");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "topic",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/Topic/{topicId?}");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

**Anchor Tag HTML for category filter:**

```
  @foreach (var category in ViewBag.Categories)
  {
      <tr>
          <td>
              @Html.RouteLink((string)category.Name, "category", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", categoryId = category.CategoryId }, new{ @class="text-decoration-none" })
          </td>
      </tr>

  }
```

**Anchor Tag HTML for Topic attribute:**

```
<li class="nav-item">
    @Html.RouteLink("Bootstrap", "topic", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", topicId = "BS" }, new{ @class="nav-link text-dark" })
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
@Html.RouteLink("C#", "topic", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", topicId = "CSHARP" }, new{ @class="nav-link text-dark" })
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
@Html.RouteLink("JavaScript", "topic", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", topicId = "JS" }, new{ @class="nav-link text-dark" })
</li>
```

Comment: The route is a string.  So just combine two strings : string base = `https://localhost:7026/home/index/category/gen/`; string route = `topic/bs`; string path = base + route;

Comment: no base is not always the same. if the page loaded first base would be like: https://localhost:7026/
and route would be like if i click category: category/gen

Comment: It is still a string.  So you may have different servers.  string server = "abc"; string base = `"https://" + "server" + ":7026/home/index/category/gen/"`

Comment: But how i do this thing to make my anchor tag link dynamic?

Comment: It just combining strings together.

Comment: @Html.RouteLink("C#", "topic", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", topicId = "CSHARP" }, new{ @class="nav-link text-dark" })
can you give me some hint code by using above or other code?

Comment: Replace hard coded string with variables like string home = "abc";

Comment: I think you don't get my point buddy. anyways I solved my problem thanks for the response.

Comment: If you have solved the issue, please post an answer and mark it as answer, it will help other folks who face the same issue.

Comment: Done. Thanks for reminding me. @BrandoZhang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the support. However, I solved my problem on my own by using TempData and setting a selected category ID value or topic ID value to it. if a category or topic is already selected based on a bool value I add a check in view file and render the Route link based on the set value like this:

**Updated Controller code:**

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(topicId))
    {
        TempData["SelectedTopicId"] = topicId;
        faqList = faqList.Where(x => x.TopicId == topicId.ToUpper()).ToList();

    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryId))
    {
        TempData["SelectedCategoryId"] = categoryId;
        faqList = faqList.Where(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId.ToUpper()).ToList();
    }
```

**Updated View code:**

For topic case:

```
string selectedCategoryId= TempData["SelectedCategoryId"] as string;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedCategoryId))
{
@Html.RouteLink((string)topic.Name, "topic", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", topicId = topic.TopicId }, new{ @class="nav-link text-gray" })
}
else
{
@Html.RouteLink((string)topic.Name, "topic_category", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", topicId = topic.TopicId, categoryId = selectedCategoryId }, new{ @class="nav-link text-gray" })
}
```

For category case:

```
string selectedTopicId = TempData["SelectedTopicId"] as string;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedTopicId))
{
@Html.RouteLink((string)category.Name, "category", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", categoryId = category.CategoryId, }, new{ @class="text-decoration-none" })
}
else
{
@Html.RouteLink((string)category.Name, "category_topic", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", categoryId = category.CategoryId, topicId = selectedTopicId }, new{ @class="text-decoration-none" })
}
```